# Fast Clustering Algorithm for Geographic Data?

Tags: algorithm, clustering

I have been browsing through the net in my attempt to find a fast clustering algorithm to cluster geographic points, but lot many of the results found were for clustering algorithm in general and not for geographic data.

Some of these algorithm expected me to specify the number of cluster in advance which is something I don't want to do?

Any suggestion to explore some algorithm?

Comment: P.P.S. What software are you using?

Comment: I am planning to code it in CoffeeScript!

Comment: Do you want this clustering to be performed on the server or on the client (on the fly)?

Comment: Julien, Thanks for writing. Not for now! Currently I am running this Model time. But may be in near future and hence wish to nail it in first go itself.

Comment: General clustering algorithms work fine for geographic data. There are many that do not require pre-specifying the numbers of clusters, especially hierarchical methods. Clustering itself is a [*huge* topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=cluster), so answering this question would require more information about your purpose and the nature of the data.

Answer (score 3):

Use Openlayers Cluster strategy which lets you display points representing clusters of features (geopoints) within some pixel distance. visit http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html for complete source code.

or check out http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/simple_example.html to create cluster maps from geo-points.

Comment: Hi Farhat, Thanks for the links, what I am looking for is an efficient Algo which I can used in my code to cluster Lat Long. So the links you sent were not somethg I was looking for. But anyways thanks! :)